# Where do I find charcoal in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

I was having a look at the craftable items in Don't Starve, and a number of them ask for Charcoal.  I figured you could just refine something to make it, but I don't see it on the list.

Is there a biome where it is found or a creature that drops it?  Or am I just being dense about not seeing how to refine it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a torch to set a tree on fire and then chop it down to get a charcoal!

Charcoal is also a loot drop from [**Krampus**](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus)!

Comment: Thanks!  I had just figured that out right when you posted.  Good answer, and welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Additionally, if you use Willow, she comes equipped with a lighter and that's great for lighting nearby things as it never loses durability :)

Comment: "A" tree? Why would you burn just *one* tree when there's a nicely-flammable *forest* out there?